# XPath for double caps text in current element text not child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

**This may look like a simple thing but is actually complex.**

My XML is below:

```
<authors>
<au>
<fnm>XXY</fnm> MArio</au>
<au>
<fnm>Xxy</fnm> MArio</au>
<au>
<fnm>XXy</fnm> Mario</au>
</authors>
```

My condition is

1. Need to find `<au>` tag with double caps but not with in **fnm** tag

Based on above XML file first two authors tags `au` should be find but not the third `au`

**I have tried the XPath code**

```
//au[text()][matches(.,'[A-Z][A-Z]')]
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `//au[text()[matches(., '[A-Z]{2}')]]`.

Comment: Be aware of the fnm-element where the text() should match the regexp. So probably : //au[fnm[matches(., '[A-Z]{2}')]] should work

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, I don't quite understand to which element your comment relates, my suggestion selects the first two `au` elements as they have text node children that match the pattern.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed: Your objection is unfounded: Martin's XPath will only select `au` elements with text children matching the pattern.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: my mistake. Is was focuced on XXY

Comment: you are genius sir.. I have tried this earlier //au[text()[matches(., '[A-Z][A-Z]')]] but not worked... now completely working fine..

Comment: @Yogib You could have used: `au[matches(text(), '[A-Z][A-Z]')]`. Just to make clear that the problem is with your brackets, not with `[A-Z][A-Z}` vs. `[A-Z]{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

[Martin's XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267498/290085) is probably what you want (+1), but in case you truly

> 1. Need to find tag with double caps but not with in `fnm` tag

then use this XPath:

```
//*[not(self::fnm) and text()[matches(., '[A-Z]{2}')]]
```

---

...after editing your question, I see a hidden `<au>` tag:

> 1. Need to find `<au>` tag with double caps but not with in `fnm` tag

I fixed this for you.  (You have to use `` `<au>` `` to escape markup and make it visible.)  So, clearly you do want what Martin has posted.